# Why doesn't the Locals window in Visual Studio show variable.Length?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have the following C# variable and code:

```
string word;
...
if (word.Length > width)
...
```

During debugging in Visual Studio 2010, the Locals window shows `word` but `word.Length` is only available as a DataTip.  Why is this, and is there a way to have the Locals window show such attributes as Length?

I am on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The debugger has hard-baked knowledge of System.String.  It doesn't show the object internals.  If you want to know the Length then you'll have to enter it as an expression in a Watch or Quick Watch or the Immediate window.  Since you use it in your code, the data tip or the Autos window suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *Locals window* show only local variables in current stack frame. Current stack frame can be selected in the *Call Stack window*.

To get the value of "word.Length" expression, you can use the *Autos window* or *Watch window*. The *Autos window* displays variables used in the current statement and the previous statement. In *Watch window* you should manually add the "word.Length" expression.

Comment: Yes, turns out it is available in the Autos window.  Thank you.